# compare current date in database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a field in database with a `DateTime` format.

I want to do a query to extract all the rows that have **this day**, but that field in database has this format: `2014-11-07 21:21:22.733`, I don't want to check the hours, seconds and minutes, I need to check just the day.

I did this:

```
string query = @"SELECT *
                 FROM Orders
                 WHERE PrintTime is NULL
                   AND CONVERT(DATE, Datelogged) = @Datelogged
                 ";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datelogged", DateTime.Today);
```

but I kept having empty results.

Comment: I don't see a reason that's not working. Can you run it directly on the database (without c#) with it working?

Comment: @gunr2171 when I run directly, I got empty reults, I do this: `SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE PrintTime is NULL AND CONVERT(DATE, Datelogged) = '2014-07-11'`

Comment: Try (in sql direct) using `CONVERT(DATE, Datelogged) between '2014-07-11' and '2014-07-12`. That's not the answer but it may help to debug this.

Comment: @gunr2171 still got empty results :(

Comment: You should make sure of what's in your database. Maybe you get empty results because there is no data for the date you're looking for.

Comment: So I have to ask the dumb question now: are you _absolutly sure_ sure you have values in your date range. Also take off your `PrintTime is NULL` to see if that is filtering too much. If you can post a quick example of the Orders table for us to see that would also help.

Comment: @gunr2171 I guess u right. the data is empty, let me check again

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what *data type* your date/time column is (`"2014-11-07 21:21:22.733"` is just a *textual representation* of the data in the column).

Assuming that your `DateLogged` column is defined as `datetime` or `datetime2` rather than, say, `varchar(32)`, you can do something like this:

```
public DataTable Fetchorders( DateTime dt )
{
  DataTable dt = new DataTable() ;

  using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection( "..." ) )
  using ( SqlCommand    cmd  = conn.CreateCommand()       )
  using ( SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)    ) 
  {
    string query = @"
      SELECT o.*
      FROM Orders o
      WHERE o.DateLogged >= @date
        and o.DateLogged <  dateadd(day,1,@date)
      " ;

    cmd.CommandText = query ;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text ;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(
       new SqlParameter( "@date" , dt.Date , SqlDbType.DateTime )
       ) ;

    conn.Open() ;
    sda.Fill(dt) ;
    conn.Close() ;

  }

  return dt ;
}
```

You want to avoid things like `convert(date,t.DateLogged)` because that converts the column into an *expression* and makes it impossible for the SQL Server optimizer to make use of any covering indices. So rather than seeking to rows in question, you might get a table scan instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use **GETDATE()** to get the current date and time from the SQL Server.

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE PrintTime is NULL AND CONVERT(DATE, Datelogged) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())";
```